# How can I modify $0 value in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to test one of my Perl scripts. I want to modify the "$0" value during compile time. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: 1) Yes it is. 2) What would you want to do? (I've done it *locally* for printing the script out of a long path name.)

Comment: Sometimes it's fun to hide who you are from ps, although I've never done it for any good reason. :)

Answer (score 8):

Whenever you have a question about a special variable, read its entry in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). Here's the first part of the entry for `$0`, which up front implies that you can assign to it:

```
   $PROGRAM_NAME
   $0      Contains the name of the program being executed.

           On some (read: not all) operating systems assigning to $0
           modifies the argument area that the "ps" program sees.
```

The entry goes on and on about the various implications of assigning to it.

Do you have an example of what you are trying to do and how it's not doing what you want it to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try it and find out.

```
$ perl -e 'print "$0\n"; $0="abcd"; print "$0\n"'
-e
abcd
```

But I'm not sure what you mean about modifying `$0` "during compile time".

Comment: Re: what he means - Perhaps a `BEGIN` block?